# Why does the image of ThumbnailCard seem broken?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I want to send to the user two `ThumbnailCards`, each one containing an image. However the images seem broken, regardless the fact that the images links are correct.

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session)  {
    var msg=new builder.Message(session);
    msg.attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel);
    msg.attachments([
        new builder.ThumbnailCard(session)
        .images([builder.CardImage.create(session, '/images/greece_round_icon_256.png')]),
        new builder.ThumbnailCard(session)
        .images([builder.CardImage.create(session, '/images/flag-english.png')])
    ]);
    session.send(msg).endDialog();
});
```

Comment: Which channel are you using?  What code are you using to return a message with the two ThumbnailCards?  What are the image links that are not working?

Comment: Plead add the code you are using.

Comment: I am using visual studio code running node.js platform and testing with botframework emulator

Comment: Have you tried using a fully qualified url?  ( something like https: //botname.azurewebsites.net/images/flag-english.png )

Comment: Dahlvang thank you very much! It worked,i was so puzzled...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to   Eric Dahlvang, the answer is simple. The path should be a url and not a local one.That's why it seems broken in the first place.